# Onsen UI ons.notification.alert issue

Tags: onsen-ui

the following code

```
var i=0;
i++;
ons.notification.alert({message: i});
i++;
ons.notification.alert({message: i});
i++;
ons.notification.alert({message: i});
```

The alert result is:

> 3
>     2
>    1

Could someone please explain the mechanism of Onsen Alert?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all displayed at the same time but the last one will be displayed on top of the others.

If you want to display them sequentially you need to use the `callback` parameter.

```
ons.notification.alert({
  message: 'First message',
  callback: function() {
    ons.notification.alert({
      message: 'Second message'
    });
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/qdoZXX

Comment: Thanks. We have to put the sequential items in callback.